# Prove that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{(a+b)^2+c^2}\ge \frac{3}{5}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

$a,b,c$ are reals $ >0$ prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b-c)^2}{(a+b)^2+c^2}\ge \frac{3}{5}$$
The inequality is homogeneous so assum WLOG $a+b+c=3$, the inequality is equivalent to $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(3-2c)^2}{(3-c)^2+c^2} \ge 3/5$$

Set $$f(x)= \frac{(3-2x)^2}{(3-x)^2+x^2} $$
We wish to prove that for $0<x<3$ we have $f(x)\ge 1/5$... but unfortunately this is false, so what should I do?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h258462

Comment: Unfortunately the minimum of $f(x)$ is 0 instead of 1/5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show $f(x)+\frac{18}{25}(x-1)\geqslant \frac15$ for all $x\in (0,3)$.